# No usable desktop on Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, xfce

My desktop on Xubuntu 16.04 can only be accessed through the system file manager. I can create a new folder or file in the Desktop folder through the file manager, but none of those can be seen from the actual Desktop.

Moreover, leftclicking or rightclicking on the desktop background doesn't produce anything. No menus, no selectionable items, nothing.

Any idea about this issue? If it helps, I am using an Asus Pc EEE 1015-PX (an unlucky device, I must say).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What file manager are you using? Sounds like thunar isn't set to manage the desktop.

Comment: I am using Thunar. It works fine, the only problem I encounter is this desktop thing where I can't create, click or do anything.